# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"logo"' can't be used to index type 'Object' in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

The problem is located on my **app.component.ts**, on line `res['logo']`

The error says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"logo"' can't be used to index type 'Object'. Property 'logo' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(7053)

What does this error means? and why I'm having a problem.

**app.component.html** (part of code):

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProfile()">
     <input (change)="onLogoSelect($event)" placeholder="Upload Company Logo" type="file" formControlName="companyLogo">
     <button (click)="onLogoUpload()">Upload Company Logo</button>

     <div *ngIf="logoUrl">
       Preview Image from AWS
       <br>
       <img src="https://logo-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/{{ logoUrl }}" alt=""> <br>
     </div>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts** (here's where the problem is showing up):

```
import { LogoUploadService } from 'app/logo/logo-upload.service';

export class EmployerAccountComponent implements OnInit {
     logoObj: File;
     logoUrl: string;
     
     constructor(
     private logoUploadService: LogoUploadService,
     ){
          ... (just some codes here)
     }
     

     onLogoSelect(event: Event): void {
          const FILE = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
          this.logoObj = FILE;
     }

     onLogoUpload() {
          const logoForm = new FormData();
          logoForm.append('logo', this.imageObj);
          this.logoUploadService.imageUpload(logoForm).subscribe(res => {
               this.logoUrl = res['logo']; // <--------------here's the problem 'res['logo']'
          });
     }
}
```

**logo-upload.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogoUploadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // API call
  logoUpload(logoForm: FormData){
    console.log('logo uploading');
    return this.http.post('arn:aws:s3:::logo-bucket', logoForm);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, if you do not pass a type to `this.httpClient.get` the response will be an `Object`. But TS can't be sure that `logo` that is a `string` is a valid key of `Object`, so it will auto convert it to type `any`

You should define the result type in the get :

`this.http.post<{logo: string}>('arn:aws:s3:::logo-bucket', logoForm);`